# Fortran sub arrays for multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, fortran

This might be quite simple,

If I have a 3D array in Fortran 90

```
REAL A(2,2,2)
```

If I pass this array to a function as

```
call function(A(:,1,:))
```

What is the equivalent 2D array going to look like?

Is it

A(1,1,1) A(1,1,2)

A(2,1,1) A(2,1,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you already wrote the correct slice of `A` as a matrix but just for clarity:

Lets define a function `f` with dummy argument `mat` aka

```
function f(mat)
  real :: mat(2,2)
  ...
end function
```

Then a call such as `f(A(:,1,:))` would yield `mat` as the following

```
mat(1,1) = A(1,1,1)
mat(2,1) = A(2,1,1)
mat(1,2) = A(1,1,2)
mat(2,2) = A(2,1,2)
```